# Visual Studio fonts & colors: html attribute quote

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For some reason when I add an attribute to HTML tags in VS with my dark theme the quotation marks are black which is difficult to work with since I have a black background. I've gone through what I thought would be the most likely places to change the color. What color listing do I need to adjust to change the color of the quotes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fonts & Colors > Xml Attribute Quotes is what you're looking for. Kind of confusing since you'd expect to see it in HTML settings.

Also, you should check some of the other XML attribute quote settings XAML, VB XML and so forth.